# Networkit not imported in jupyter note book

Tags: python, import, jupyter-notebook, installation, networkit

I am using Macbook pro and in my system I install networkit using

```
pip3 install networkit
```

but when ever I am importing networkit in jupyter notebook using

```
import networkit as nk
```

it throws an error

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'networkit'"
```

How to solve this?

Comment: Hi! is the Jupyter notebook running against the same python installation? How do you start the notebook server?

Comment: First I open my terminal and there I type Jupyter notebook .

Comment: could you try `python3 -m jupyter notebook`?

Comment: Now I tried . It says " No module named jupyter "

Comment: Problem is solved. Now I again install jupyter as " pip3 install jupyter " . After that I run "python3 -m jupyter notebook" . And now the problem is solved. Can you tell me the reason why this happend?